# How do I pass the value of a variable from one IF to another, inside one function?

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

friends!

There is a code:

```py
    
 elif 'all_record' in call.data:
            status = call.data.split(':')[1]
        
            if status == 'show_records':
                all_record = core.all_records()
                for record in all_record:
                    rec_user_id = record[0]
                    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f" Запись на услугу: <b>{record[2]}</b>\n\n\n‍ Пользователь: <b>{record[1]}</b>\n\n Дата записи: <b>{record[3]}</b>\n\n⌚️ Время записи: <b>{record[4]}</b>", parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup.markip_admin_record())
                    

    
            if status == 'confirm_record':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f"{record[1]}, Ваша запись успешно завершена!:  ")
                bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
            if status == 'cancel_recording':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Ваша запись Отменена  ")
                bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJlWB.png)

The Pytelegrambotapi library. The bot uploads a list of all customer records from the database and the user has a choice: Confirm(callback_data= confirm_record) /Cancel recording(callback_data=cancel_recording).

The actual question:

Please tell me how to pass the value of the record variable so that the bot does not just output a message, but indicates a specific record!

Thanks!

I tried to create separate tables in the database, tried global variables and concatenation methods - I can't figure out how to do this, since the for loop outputs only the last result to separate variables (

Comment: Ignoring the fact that `record` is *only* defined when `status == 'show_records'`, it is assignment multiple different values over the course of the loop. What *value* do you expect to use with the other values of `status`?

Comment: @chepner   the "status" determines which callback command is pressed, it does not interact with variables. I extracted the values from the database through a loop, the bot printed them (several pieces) and in each bot message there are two callback buttons - accept/reject, depending on the choice, the bot should write to the user, your entry is canceled or confirmed! (the ID of all users is stored in the rec_user_id variable)

Comment: @chepner status = call.data.split(':')[1] defines status, not the == check. == is not an assignment.

Comment: I never said `==` defines `status`. I said `record` is only defined *when* `status` has a specific value.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear to me, but it seem like you need to put the record readout under this line:

```
status = call.data.split(':')[1]
```

This keeps it outside of the IF-statements and will be the same for each IF.

Comment: the "status" determines which callback command is pressed, it does not interact with variables. I extracted the values from the database through a loop, the bot printed them (several pieces) and in each bot message there are two callback buttons - accept/reject, depending on the choice, the bot should write to the user, your entry is canceled or confirmed! (the ID of all users is stored in the rec_user_id variable)